# Querying data from Neo4j using spring data returns null all the time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data

I am trying to use neo4j using spring boot and spring data.
I have stored data in my neo4j already and all my queries are returning null unless I store the data using my app which kind of made me confused.
I thought maybe I am using an embedded database but I guess that is not the case as I don't have it on my dependencies.
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4jpoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- add this dependency if you want to use the bolt driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- add this dependency if you want to use the HTTP driver -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=neo4j
logging.level.org.neo4j.driver.GraphDatabase = debug
logging.level.org.neo4j.driver.Driver = debug
logging.level.org.neo4j.driver.OutboundMessageHandler = debug
logging.level.org.neo4j.driver.InboundMessageDispatcher = debug
```

Here is my db.properties:

```
URI=bolt://localhost
username=neo4j
password=neo4j
```

Here is my entity:

```
package me.neo4j.neo4jpoc.graph.entity;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Property;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@NodeEntity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Property(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "CONSISTS_OF", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    public Set<MyEntity> children;

    @Relationship(type = "BELONGS_TO", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    public Set<MyEntity> parents;

    public void consistsOf(MyEntity child) {
        if (children == null) {
            children = new HashSet<>();
        }
        children.add(child);
    }

    public void belongsTo(MyEntity parent) {
        if (parents == null) {
            parents = new HashSet<>();
        }
        parents.add(parent);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name + "'s children => "
                + Optional.ofNullable(this.children).orElse(
                Collections.emptySet()).stream()
                .map(MyEntity::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()) + "'s parents => "
                + Optional.ofNullable(this.parents).orElse(
                Collections.emptySet()).stream()
                .map(MyEntity::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Here is my spring data repository:

```
package me.neo4j.neo4jpoc.graph.repo;

import me.neo4j.neo4jpoc.graph.entity.MyEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (l:MAIN) RETURN l")
    MyEntity findQuery();
}
```

Here is my spring boot configuration:

```
package me.neo4j.neo4jpoc;

import org.neo4j.ogm.config.ClasspathConfigurationSource;
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "me.neo4j.neo4jpoc.graph.repo")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration) {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory(configuration, "me.neo4j.neo4jpoc.graph.entity");
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        ConfigurationSource properties = new ClasspathConfigurationSource("db.properties");
        return new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(properties).build();
    }


}
```

and finally here is my spring boot application class:

```
package me.neo4j.neo4jpoc;

import me.neo4j.neo4jpoc.graph.entity.MyEntity;
import me.neo4j.neo4jpoc.graph.repo.MyEntityRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AccessingDataNeo4jApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessingDataNeo4jApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataNeo4jApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner run(MyEntityRepository repository) {
        return args -> {

            MyEntity myEntity = repository.findQuery();
            System.out.println("myEntity = " + myEntity);
            LOG.debug("myEntity = {}", myEntity);
        };
    }
}
```

Also here is the cyphers for storing the data which I have stored inside my neo4j database through neo4j browser:

```
CREATE(l:PARENT {NAME:'ParentX'})
CREATE(w:MAIN {NAME:'Node1'})
CREATE(t:CHILD {NAME:'ChildY'})
CREATE (l)-[:CONSISTS_OF]->(w),(w)-[:CONSISTS_OF]->(t)
CREATE (l)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(w),(w)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)
```

Any input would be appreciated as I have no clue why it is not retrieving data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (single) entity class is named `MyEntity` and its `@NodeEntity` annotation does not specify the `label` name, so the associated node label defaults to `MyEntity` as well. Therefore, your Java code will only create and search for nodes with the `MyEntity` label.

On the other hand, your Cypher code is creating nodes with the labels `PARENT`, `MAIN`, and `CHILD`.

This is why your Java code never finds any nodes created by your Cypher code.

You will have change your Java and/or Cypher code to use the same node label(s). And you may also need to update the existing nodes in the DB to use the proper label(s).

Comment: So does it mean for each label I need to have a seperate class annotated by @NodeEntity?
Here I need to add MainEntity, ParentEntity and ChildEntity. Right?

Comment: Ok stupid mistake.
I should design my graph all over again.
Thanks @cybersam

Comment: By the way, Do you know if there is any way to have relationship with unknown types?
What I mean is that assume that the parent in my graph can have multiple children of different types.
One  child of type MAIN, two of type AUX and 2 of type AUX2.
But then I want to load all of them in the same collection as all of them are children of parent but then I don't want them to have the same label in neo4j.

Comment: Sure. See the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-relationship) for some more info. Create a new question if you still need help.